# How to set cell height in WxPython Grid

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxGrid that I set up as shown below, however am not able to figure out how to let the height of the cells adjust itself because some of the text has line breaks and I have to drag a cell down in order to view the full text.

```
self.grid = wx.grid.Grid(self.motherboard_Panel, 5, wx.DefaultPosition, (850, 1000), 0, '')
self.total_Rows = len(items)
self.headers = ["Sales", "Purchases"]
self.total_Columns = len(items[0])
self.grid.CreateGrid(self.total_Rows, len(items[0]))
self.grid.SetRowLabelSize(0)
self.grid.SetSelectionMode(wx.grid.Grid.SelectRows)
self.grid.SetColFormatNumber(3)
for index, value in enumerate(self.headers):
    self.grid.SetColSize(index, 420)
    self.grid.SetColLabelValue(index, str(value.capitalize()))
for overall_index, value in enumerate(items):
    for index, value in enumerate(value):
        self.grid.SetCellValue(overall_index, index, str(value))
        self.grid.SetCellAlignment(overall_index, index, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        if index == 0:
            self.grid.SetReadOnly(overall_index, index, True)
self.parent_vertical_BoxSizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 20)
```

Comment: Without wishing to be flippant `cell height` is in fact the height of the  `row` in a grid. Perhaps you worded your question loosely. In a grid the cell dimensions are defined by row height and column width.

Answer (score 0):

Cell height is equivalent to a row height, therefore to make it work I used this:

```
for index, value in enumerate(items):
   self.grid.SetRowSize(index, 600)
```

Where SetRowSize(), accepts height which is the second parameter and the first parameter being the index.